# Resume Training from max epoch saved in csv file in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

i am trying to train a VGG16 model on dataset with 35k images  on 100 epochs but my GPU RAM out of memory and training stop at 40 epochs. It gives an error

> ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,64,224,224] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
> [[node gradient_tape/sequential_3/vgg16/block1_conv2/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput (defined at :1) ]]
> Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
> [Op:__inference_train_function_12670]

Function call stack:
train_function

Now i want to resume training from the last epoch data saved in csv file , is that possible ? Training from scratch is very time consuming and everytime RAM goes out of memory.

Here is my code

```
learning_rate = 5e-5
epochs = 100
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto', restore_best_weights=True)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, min_lr=0.001)
csv_logger = CSVLogger('trainSelfVGG.csv', separator=',')
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("VGGSelf_model.h5", monitor = 'val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=tensorflow.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate,clipnorm=1.), metrics = ['acc'])
```

in my directory i have "VGGSelf_model.h5" file and "trainSelfVGG.csv" file but don't know how to resume training after reading csv file.
Please help my csv file look like this
[image: csv file with epochs, accuracy, val_acc,loss and val_loss]

Comment: Please check callback Checkpoint: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint

Comment: No that csv file only saves losses values. You have a model checkpoint callback. does this call back save any model? the name should be VGGSelf_model.h5

Comment: Yes i have model with VGGSelf_model.h5 file can it be helpful for me for resume training. This csv file also have accuracy.

Comment: Do you find the solution?